# Android resource linking failed at `AndroidManifest.xml`

Tags: android, xml, gradle

I was running my app to test it on AVD and I get an error.

It takes some time to build output, then the error comes out, the error is located at `AndroidManifest.xml` and the part of the error and error log is below!

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/AdAppID" />
```

`Error`

```
C:\Users\osedk\Desktop\muslim\Muslim-App\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:67:9-69:47: AAPT: error: resource string/AdAppID (aka com.toolsandapps4us.muslimapp:string/AdAppID) not found.
```

Comment: Have you declared `AdAppID` inside `/res/values/strings.xml` ?

Comment: No, I search for `AdAppID` it's not there. Can you help me how to declare it ?

Comment: `how to declare it` the same as any other string you would declare inside strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

The  **"@string/AdAppID"** not defined in your ***string.xml***  You have need to define AdAppId --->

Google gave update for the Google ads so if you update your Admob library in gradle then you need to add this in your manifest -->

```
<manifest>
<application>
  <!-- TODO: Replace with your real AdMob app ID -->
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value="ca-app-pub-################~##########"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Read the [android official documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)

Comment: I did it, but now another error saying `package android.support.v7.app` and such on does not exist

Comment: please upgrade your dependencies  or  you can do upgrade into androidx